# I want to get 3 records from my table in Json format but getting duplicates

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, gson

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   try{

       Employee emp=new Employee();
       DBrelation db=new DBrelation();
       Connection cn=db.getConnect();
       PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from sbh");
       ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

      Gson gson=new Gson();     

      ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<Object>();
      ArrayList<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();

       while(rs.next())
       {
        emp.setEmp_Id(rs.getInt(1));      
        emp.setEmp_Name(rs.getString(2)); 
        emp.setDesignation(rs.getString(3));
        list.clear();
        list.add(rs.getString(4));list=null;
        emp.setSkills(list);
        al.add(emp); 

       }


      String st=gson.toJson(al);  

      out.println("{\"sbh\":"+st+"}");

        cn.close();
}

catch(Exception e)
{ e.printStackTrace();}


}
}
```

output I am gettng: {"sbh":[{"Emp_Id":1003,"Emp_Name":"james","Designation":"Zonal Manager","Skills":["oracle,MySQL,SQL Server"]},{"Emp_Id":1003,"Emp_Name":"james","Designation":"Zonal Manager","Skills":["oracle,MySQL,SQL Server"]},{"Emp_Id":1003,"Emp_Name":"james","Designation":"Zonal Manager","Skills":["oracle,MySQL,SQL Server"]}]}

output required :  {"sbh":[{"Emp_Id":1001,"Emp_Name":"jamee","Designation":"asst Manager","Skills":["oracle"]},{"Emp_Id":1002,"Emp_Name":"jos","Designation":"gen Manager","Skills":["MySQL"]},{"Emp_Id":1003,"Emp_Name":"johns","Designation":"chief Manager","Skills":["SQL Server"]}]}

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same employee to the list every time, and then updating its fields as you go along. Create a new employee object in your loop:

```
   while(rs.next())
   {
    emp=new Employee();
    ...
```